# Adding an item to a listview in a different activity from the current activity on click of a button

Tags: android, listview, dynamic, android-activity

I want to add an item to a listview that is present in a different activity from the current activity. Say I have a button in my current activity and when this button is clicked I want to add an item to the listview present in a different activity. Can anybody suggest me a work around for this? Thank you.

Comment: will you be calling new activity on this button click or just want to populate a listview for another activity? if just adding an item to activity you should should consider on creating a shared storage for such things either store the items in a databse or xml file or shared preferences if the data is not related and is of one kind say key=value pairs.

Comment: no I just want to populate the items to the listview in a different activity.

Comment: So basically you populate a storage then on launch of your second activity you read the items from it. that's about it.

Comment: what will be the best way to do it? I have many activities that will have the add button which will add items to the listview. Please suggest me a solution.

Comment: many activities populate same list. aye, you can store everything in one place like a storage/db/xml then read it upon a launch of the needed listview activity. here's an example of listview and db usage http://kahdev.wordpress.com/2010/09/27/android-using-the-sqlite-database-with-listview/

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Intents`.

You have to launch your 2nd Activity with a  `startActivityForResult (Intent intent, int requestCode)`. Then before terminating it you must put the data that you wish to add to the 1st Activity in an `Intent`.

Finally, in your first `Activity`, you get this data in the `onActivityResult()` method.

Here's a detailled example: http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/notepad/notepad-ex2.html

Answer (score 0):

you should use startActivityForResult(for start SelectorActivity) in current activity(lets call it ListActivity)
then in second activity (lets call it SelectorActivity) you have to put some confirm button(OK) and when you click OK button you should call setResult and finish SelectorActivity

back in ListActivity you should override onActivityResult and add data from SelectorActivity to list Adapter

first look here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#StartingActivities

Edit: you should return data in Intent ... use Intent.putExtra() in setResult and then Intent.getExtra() in onActivityResult

Comment: But I have an  issue I dont want to start the activity when button is clicked.

Comment: so where is this Activity (Selector) started

Answer (score 0):

When the button is clicked store the data in shared preference and when u are starting the list activity get the data from shared preference and populate the list delete the data from the shared preference